# How to handle data for a recyclerview with multiple view types?

Tags: android

Lets say we are coding the facebook home page. There are different type of rows like photo posts, advertisements, the good morning header, info that your friend has a new friend and stuff like that. We would use a recyclerview with multiple view types for this.

But how do we handle the data? Each viewholder would require a different POJO model. When there is only one viewtype, I pass an arraylist with required type to the adapter. But what to do in this case?

Comment: You should pass an array of generics and depending on the instance of each object you should give it the corresponding layout/logic

Comment: In this case, we will make different model classes for different layout structure and pass model class name when calling adapter and check for that by using "instanceOf" for indentifying current model in this layout.

Comment: Like pass an arraylist of objects to adapter and cast them later?

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a `BaseViewHolder` class which will extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

2- Create an `enum` named `ViewType` :

```
public enum ViewType {
    POST, IMAGE, VIDEO
}
```

3- Create a `ViewModel` class which will hold the data like this:

```
public class ViewModel {

    ViewType viewType;
    Object value;

    public ViewType getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setViewType(ViewType viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

4- Your RecyclerView Adapter will hold a BaseViewHolder:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(...) {

    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    switch(cardType) {

        case 1:
            viewModel.setViewType(ViewType.POST);
            break;

        case 2:
            viewModel.setViewType(ViewType.POST);

        break;
        }

    return BaseViewHolder.createView(viewModel);
    }
}
```

5- The BaseViewHolder class is:

```
public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

    }

    public static BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(ViewModel model) {

        View itemView;
        switch(model.getViewType()) {

            case POST:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout);
            return new PostLayoutViewHolder(itemView, model);

            case IMAGE:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_layout);
            return new ImageLayoutViewHolder(itemView, model);

        }

    }
}
```

6- For every view type, you will create a ViewHolder class that extends BaseViewHolder.

Comment: consider using generics rather than plain Object

Comment: later at this code, in onBindViewHolder method, I would need to check the type of that object and cast it. Are you sure this is a good way?

Comment: only on ViewHolder you need to cast it.
but in the onBindViewHolder you need to set the value of the object, and call `viewHolder.initializeView()` and then in the ViewHolder you should cast the Object

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

For models create a base decorator class such as

```
public abstract BaseDecorator<T> {
    private final T model;

    public BaseDecorator(@NonNull T model){
        this.model = model;
    }

    public T getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public abstract int getViewType();

}
```

That way you have a decorator that holds you domain model and let you add UI related logic (viewtype for instance).

Create sub classes for each data needed (POST,FRIEND REQUEST ETC) and let each sub class define getViewType returning a unique value for each child (you could store those view types in a @IntDef or utility class for cleaner code)

Now your adapter only needs a list of `BaseDecorator` to handle data. Then on `onCreateViewHolder` you can switch the received viewType and create the correct ViewHolder.

Ofcourse override your adapter's `getViewType`method, something like this

```
  @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return decorators.get(position).getViewType();
}
```